# How to User Variable Names For Opening One or More Files In Python?

Tags: python

Python newb and first-time poster...

I'm building a mass disk copying program and have been pretty successful in working through issues until now. I am trying to open from 1 to n (up to 28) files (actually drives in Linux, e.g., /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd, ...), depending on user checkbox selection.

I'm using something like below, but of course am getting a "can't assign to function call" error when the code hits the eval line. This is not the actual code, but replicates my problem; please ignore the file paths.

What is an appropriate way to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class snippet:
    def __init__(self):
        # open files for binary writing
        file_in = open('/dev/null', 'rb')
        ints = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        for i in ints:
            num = str(i)
                eval('f_out' + num) = open('/tmp/tmp' + num, 'wb') 

        # READ/WRITE CODE GOES HERE 

        # close files
        file_in.close()
        for i in ints:
            num = str(i)
            print "Number: " + num
            eval("f_out" + num).close() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = snippet()
```

Thanks,
   Roy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use eval; keep a dictionary *(Edit: or list)* of file handles instead of individually named variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    outfiles = [open("/tmp/tmp{0}".format(i), 'wb') for i in (0,1,2,3)]

    with open('/dev/null', 'rb') as inf:
        # do reading/writing
        pass

    for i,f in enumerate(outfiles):
        print("Closing number {0}".format(i))
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If they're indexed by number, you could just use a list.

Comment: Hugh, Thank you very much, I think I can make this concept work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list of `file` objects for this. It is generally considered a bad idea to use `eval`. In any case, the use of `eval` in your program is not correct. But you can use `exec` to do the same thing, which also is not recommended.

```
exec("f_out%d = open('%s%d', 'wb')" % (num, "/tmp/tmp", num))
```

You should use something like :

```
open_files = []
num = 4
for i in range(num):
    open_files.append(open("/tmp/tmp" + i, 'wb'))
```

Comment: Thanks Rumple, I have to play with both your's and Hugh's code to integrate into my actual code. From my novice perspective, you're both creating a dictionary and populating it, correct?

Comment: @Roy: Both solutions are using a `list` and not a `dict`

Comment: Thanks again. I'm still trying to keep the types of enclosures straight for the various data types.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `eval()` to create a bunch of named file objects, which you'll need to `eval()` again anytime you want to operate on one, it would be better to store them all, maybe even the input file, in one or more lists and then process those as needed. For one thing, this would make it very easy to perform generic operations on them as a group, as well as change the number of them. For example:

```
class Snippet:
    NUM_OUTPUT_FILES = 4
    FILE_NAMES = (['/dev/null'] +
                  ['/tmp/tmp%d' % n for n in xrange(NUM_OUTPUT_FILES)])
    def __init__(self):
        # open all the files
        self.files = ([open(self.FILE_NAMES[0], 'rb')] +
                       map(lambda fname: open(fname, 'wb'), self.FILE_NAMES[1:]))
    def run(self):
        # READ/WRITE CODE GOES HERE
        # for example
        # data = self.files[0].read(1024)
        # self.files[1].write(data)
        # data = self.files[0].read(1024)
        # self.files[3].write(data)

        # close all files opened
        map(file.close, self.files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Snippet()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Martineau, Thanks for this. To verify my thoughts on your last line, it is closing all the open files in the list 'f', correct?

Comment: @Roy: No, it's *attempting* to close all the *whatever state* files in the list `files`. It's the same as `[f.close() for f in files]`. Each of the two statements produces a meangingless list `[None, None, ...]` which is ignored. You could also do this: `for f in files: f.close()`

Comment: @Roy: It makes sure all the files in the list are closed and produces a list of `None` values as a side effect (which is simply ignored).